# Freegeoip with Docker Cloud

Tags: docker, freegeoip

I am using http://freegeoip.net for geo location on my website. To reach higher reliability, I would like to create a local copy of the service on a separate server.

I have set up Docker cloud with Amazon AWS and installed this repository: https://hub.docker.com/r/fiorix/freegeoip/.

If I enter e.g. "curl localhost:8080/json/1.2.3.4" in the Docker terminal, it correctly answers with the location of that IP address.

I now want to integrate this into my website. So far my website source code references the address "//freegeoip.net/json/". By which IP address do I have to replace this to get to my copy on Docker cloud? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace with the address of your Amazon AWS instance or load balancer.